# How does one navigate between pages while maintaining state whilst using <ons-navigator>?

Tags: onsen-ui

I have 3 main pages: List (of businesses), Search, and Favourites. From the list page users can drill down into details about a business.

I am using <ons-navigator>. Navigating from list to details and back to list is working as expected since I am using <ons-back-button>. The list page state is maintained since Onsen-UI is doing a popPage().

My question is how do I navigate back to list from favourites or search while maintaining the list state? Right now I am using pushPage() but that keeps adding pages to the stack. I don't think that's how it's supposed to work and practically speaking if you push a page to the page stack and it already exists... it shouldn't be added but rather it should be moved to the top. Just an idea.

My code:

```
<ons-navigator var="app.navi" page="list.html"></ons-navigator>

<ons-template id="list.html">
    <ons-page id="list-page">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Near Me</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <ons-list></ons-list>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="search.html">
    <ons-page id="search-page">        
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Search</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="favourites.html">
    <ons-page id="favourites-page">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Favourites</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="detail.html">
    <ons-page id="detail-page">            
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left">
                <ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button>
            </div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <ons-list></ons-list>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-template id="sub-detail-page.html">
    <ons-page id="sub-detail-page">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
            <div class="center">Sub Detail Page</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>

$( $lstElmnt.children('.item'), this ).on( 'click', function() {
    currentItem = getEstablishment( $( this ).attr( 'id' ), app.navi.pushPage( 'detail.html' ) );          
});
```

Other things I have tried include carousel, tabbar, and plain old JQuery.

Comment: The `<ons-tab>` component has a `persistent` attribute. By using that the pages are not destroyed when you switch tab.

Comment: @AndreasArgelius thank you for suggesting the configuration on the tabbar. That however wouldn't work in my case since I need to navigate to subpages within a tab - which I understand is not possible...

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [gist](https://gist.github.com/lucnaterop/c7be4942a90f5fab001a00d44aea0ee6) on how to do this with react using `RouterNavigator`